# How do I update Java 8 in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, java, update

My Raspberry Pi 3 came with Java version 1.8.0_65 installed. I could not update it to a later version using `apt-get` - I assume there's no Debian repo for it. I do not know how to update it, and installing a newer version does not replace the existing one.

What's the bet way to install/update Java on Raspbian, and keep it updated going forward?

Comment: There's a rather fiddly process involving calling [update-alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk/159585#159585 "update-alternatives") for each component of the JRE/JDK. Oracle doesn't provide an auto-update service, as you need to manually log in to their site to download updates.Unless this is mission critical, I'd stick with the default Raspbian oracle-java8-jdk

Comment: @traveling-tech-guy If any of the answers below, answered your question, please mark them so. If you solved it in a different way, please post an answer to your own question and mark that.

Comment: @not2qubit none did, I had to uninstall and re-install. See my comment to second answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have all the time the most recent Oracle java installed, you can do
check current Java

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version java version "1.8.0_65" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

remove OpenJDK

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```

add digital key

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com EEA14886
```

add packet source

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**add** following lines

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

install Java 8

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

remove old Java

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo apt-get purge java7*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

check success

```
java -version
```

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -version java version "1.8.0_131" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
>   (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Great answer. I only had to notice that the command `apt-key` was pasted  with the `–` long dash, which at some point had to accidentally replace double dashes `--` so the command did not work, and resulted in weird error: `gpg: conflicting commands`. 
I have edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: This didn't work with Rasbian Stretch. The instructions at https://gist.github.com/ribasco/fff7d30b31807eb02b32bcf35164f11f worked for me.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge java7*` removed `oracle-java8-jdk`...

Answer (score 3):

The following advice by hannes ach and SWilk was successful, but I got the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C2518248EEA14886 
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.hVyJ3FPvDb/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C2518248EEA14886 
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory 
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.hVyJ3FPvDb/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory 
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

In order to resolve that, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install dirmngr --install-recommends
```

then

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com C2518248EEA14886
```

Then, everything worked as expected.

Original info from here
https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/11/02/how-to-fix-missing-dirmngr/

Answer (score 1):

If you want new features now it's possible to get version 9 and 10 like this:

```
wget https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/10/bellsoft-jre10-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.debsudo
apt install ./bellsoft-jre10-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
```

Liberica for Raspberry Pi: https://www.bell-sw.com/java-for-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this guide yet? 
http://elinux.org/RPi_Java#Installing_Java_on_Raspberry_Pi

OpenJDK

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Oracle Java 8

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/JavaFXarm/jdk-8-ea-b36e-linux-arm-hflt-29_nov_2012.tar.gz
tar zxf jdk-8-ea-b36e-linux-arm-hflt-29_nov_2012.tar.gz
rm jdk-8-ea-b36e-linux-arm-hflt-29_nov_2012.tar.gz
sudo mv ./jdk1.8.0/ /opt/
sudo chown root:root -R /opt/jdk1.8.0/
sudo ln -s /opt/jdk1.8.0/ /opt/jdk8
```

Edit `sudo nano -w /etc/profile` and add

```
PATH="$PATH":/opt/jdk8/bin
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk8

java -version
```

to see if java is working

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question, but I already have Java 8 installed. My question has to do with updating to newer versions.

Comment: Does not work, the apt-get installed Java is taking precedence on the path since it is in `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: These are very old instructions, and are no longer valid

Comment: +1 to switch to openjdk, be it for 7 or 8 if possible. It's much easier to keep current than manually download new releases from the oracle web-page than with a simple apt. The default version can easily be switched with `sudo update-alternatives --config java; sudo update-alternatives --config java` and only needs to be done once.